# I am trying to use python and selenium to create a driver scraper, I need to grab particular data from the web page and put it in csv row and column

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, csv, beautifulsoup

Here is my code
using the website: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-15-5520-laptop/drivers

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
   list = f.readlines()

for items in list:
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/util/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get(items)
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Show all')]"))).click()
   my_buttons=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='details-control js-details-toggle pointer-cursor btn collapse-toggle table-collapse-toggle js-collapse-toggle collapsed']")
   print(f"Found {len(my_buttons)} buttons")
   for button in my_buttons:
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", button)
      button.click()
   page = driver.page_source
   driver.close()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
   results = soup.find(id='downloads-table')
   results2 = results.find_all(class_='dl-desk-view') #name
   results3 = results.find_all(class_='details-control sorting_1')#type
   results4 = results.find_all(class_='details-control', text=re.compile("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec")) #date
   #results5 = severity
   #results6 = description
   #results7 = version
   #results8 = file name
   results9 = results.find_all('a', class_='btn-download-lg btn btn-sm no-break text-decoration-none dellmetrics-driverdownloads btn-outline-primary') #download url
   new_name = items.replace('https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/','').replace('/drivers','').replace('\n','')
   open('C:/temp/' + new_name + '.csv', "w").close   
   with open('C:/temp/' + new_name + '.csv', "a") as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
      writer.writerow(['Name', 'Type', 'Date', 'Severity', 'Description', 'Version', 'File Name', 'Download URL'])
   with open('C:/temp/' + new_name + '.csv', "a") as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
      for r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9 in zip(results2, results3, results4, results5, results6, results7, results8, results9):
          writer.writerow([r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9])
```

Here is an image of what I am trying to get:
[image]

So far I have been able to get the name, date, and type (BIOS) but I need to get Version, File Name, Severity to be in its own column (right now the urgent shows in the name), and Description.

I have tried using this, but it grabs more than I want it to:

```
re.findall('Version</span></p><p class="mb-0">(.*)</div><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"><p class="mb-0"><span class="font-weight-medium text-dark">Last Updated Date', str(results))
```

Is there some better way to get the information I want and add it to the particular column in the csv that i want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the API to get all the data you want? This way you get the entire response and you can either dump it to a `JSON` file, filter for items that you want and save it as `.csv` or whatever else you need and/or want to do.

Try this:

```
import csv
import time
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

product_code = "precision-15-5520-laptop"
dell_api = "https://www.dell.com/support/driver/en-uk/ips/api/driverlist/getdriversbyproduct?"

headers = {
    "referer": f"https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/{product_code}/drivers",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
payload = {
    "productcode": product_code,
    "oscode": "WT64A",
    "lob": "Dell Precision Mobile WorkStation",
    "initialload": True,
    "_": time.time() * 1000,
}

updates_data = requests.get(f"{dell_api}{urlencode(payload)}", headers=headers).json()

row_headers = [
    "Release Date", "Last Update", "Version",
    "Update status", "File Name", "Description",
]

rows = [
    [
        driver['ReleaseDate'],
        driver['LUPDDate'],
        driver['DellVer'],
        driver['Imp'],
        driver['FileFrmtInfo']['FileName'],
        # driver['BrfDesc']  uncomment this to get the description
    ] for driver in updates_data["DriverListData"]
]

with open("dell_updates_data.csv", "w") as output:
    w = csv.writer(output)
    w.writerow(row_headers)
    w.writerows(rows)

print(tabulate(rows, headers=row_headers))
```

Output:

```
Release Date    Last Update    Version                Update status    File Name
--------------  -------------  ---------------------  ---------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28 Sep 2020     13 Oct 2020    5.2.1.12926, A00       Recommended      SupportAssist-Update-Plugin-Application_6HWP6_WIN_5.2.1.12926_A00.EXE
14 Sep 2020     14 Sep 2020    5.1.89.0, A00          Recommended      Dell-PremierColor-Software-Application_2GH2M_WIN64_5.1.89.0_A00.EXE
03 Sep 2020     23 Sep 2020    1.1.112.0, A00         Recommended      Dell-Optimizer_06RN7_WIN_1.1.112.0_A00.EXE
19 Aug 2020     19 Aug 2020    8.1.958.0, A01         Recommended      nVIDIA-Control-Panel_D66P1_WIN64_8.1.958.0_A01.EXE
30 Jul 2020     28 Sep 2020    1.0.26.0, A08          Recommended      Intel-Thunderbolt-Controller-Application_TAPOF_WIN64_1.0.26.0_A08_02.EXE
12 May 2020     12 Oct 2020    4.0.52.0, A17          Optional         Dell-Alienware-Digital-Delivery-Application_PDKG8_WIN_4.0.52.0_A17.EXE
02 Nov 2020     02 Nov 2020    6.0.9025.1, A03        Recommended      Realtek-High-Definition-Audio-Driver_JJWPF_WIN_6.0.9025.1_A03.EXE
07 Sep 2020     07 Sep 2020    6.0.9008.1, A03        Recommended      Realtek-Audio-Driver_3D5WW_WIN_6.0.9008.1_A03.EXE
07 May 2020     14 Oct 2020    3.0.30.0, A02          Recommended      Waves-MaxxAudio-Pro-Application_M96FF_WIN64_3.0.30.0_A02_01.EXE
15 Sep 2020     15 Sep 2020    1.4.0, 1.4.0           Urgent           Precision_5550_1.4.0.exe

and so on ...
```

Comment: Interesting, this pulls it from the front facing site?? or from dl.dell.com? I just ask, cause the dl.dell.com is being removed

Comment: It's actually the other way round, the front page *pulls* this as its content that you see in the browser. And I'm not sure what you mean by `dl.dell.com` being removed.

Comment: You're API url is different than the one I use in the code. The code works fine for me if I change `product_code` to, say, `precision-m5510-workstation`.

Comment: Changing the `oscode` or language from `en-uk` to `en-us` still works for me. I cannot reproduce your issues without more details.

Comment: ok, I got it working, the other way i was doing it actually involved powershell and not python. I had assumed that it would have the same result, sorry for the mistake. Still learning.

Comment: I do have one other question though, the output has empty rows between each driver, do you know why this might be?

Comment: There shouldn't be any empty rows. None appear in the CSV file nor in the console output. Again. cannot reproduce. By the way, if you find my answer useful, consider up-voting and/or accepting it.

Comment: would you mind if i ask you another question? may need to do in private chat. I am having trouble making it iterable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224116/discussion-between-baduker-and-kstro).

Comment: Hey I thought of one more question? I am trying to figure out what I need to grab the URL for the driver update. I used to use httpfilelocation, but that does not seem to be working. Where did you find the information for what to search for in the py script?